# PXSelector with required gives error

Tags: acumatica

The Required in Search is giving the following error

```
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPEmployeePosition.employeeID, 
    Where<EPEmployeePosition.positionID, 
    Equal<Required<EPEmployeePosition.positionID>>>>.Select(this,'DEV')))]

    error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
    error CS1026: ) expected
    error CS1003: Syntax error, ']' expected
    error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member 
    declaration
    error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
```

Can someone let me know how to specify string constant in Search<>

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix an attribute with a function call. You can't do that in C#. The 'DEV' literal is also enclosed in a single quote instead of a double quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper way to achieve this would be with a string constant:

```
private class Dev : Constant<string>
{
    public Dev() : base("DEV")
    {
    }
}

[PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPEmployeePosition.employeeID, 
                   Where<EPEmployeePosition.positionID, 
                   Equal<Dev>>>))]
```

Comment: Also, conventions in acumatica is that ID field like PositionID is an integer key, the string field would be the substitute key CD like PositionCD.